# Rails Searchkick Elasticsearch to match multiple word search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have product model that had **name, gender, description** etc columns and those **columns are included in elasticsearch index via search_data** method.

Let's assume that I have a product with following values

```
name: 'No Boyfriend No Problem Crop Jumper'
gender : 'women'
description: 'Best crop jumber for now'
```

When I search with a term "women crop jumper"

The product doesn't appear in the search result.
I am trying to search the products with following query

```
@products = Product.search(
              params[:q],
              fields: [:gender, :name, :description],
              match: :word_start,
              page: params[:page],
              per_page: Product::PAGE
            )
```

How should I update my product search so that "women crop jumper" search terms result will include the product above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this isn't possible](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/727) as of right now. However, you could do the following and it should work:

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    gender: gender,
    description: description,
    all_fields: [name, gender, description].compact.join(' ')
  }
end
```

Then you can just search the `all_fields` field in your query.